# Logon process failed. Windows cannot load classes registry file

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts, microsoft-account

I have Windows 8.1 (64Bit). After trying today to log in to my account (user account) I get immediately signed out without even being signing in. I restarted my PC but the problem is still there. I can log in to my Administrator Account without problems. My PC has one Administrator Account and one User Account.

In the Event Viewer I get the message:

> Level: Error 
>   Event ID: 1542 
> Source: User Profile Service 
>  Windows cannot load
>   classes registry file. The system cannot find the file specified.

---

> Level: Warning 
>   Event ID: 4006 
>  Source: Winlogon 
>  The Windows logon process
>   has failed to spawn a user application. Apllication name: . Command
>   line parameters: C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe

I tried to restore to earlier date but there is no restore point created. On my laptop I can login in the User Account that is not working on my PC.

Anyone any ideas what I could do ?

Comment: If you have a restoration point I would use that.  Otherwise I would create a new user profile and transfer the old profile's files to its profile folder by taking ownership of the old folder.  I have only see the registry become corrupt when two things happen in all my years of using Windows, the first is when people use registry cleaners the second I when there is a underline system storage device problem.

Comment: No I do not use registry cleaners. Yesterday everything was fine, but today I get the above problem. I remember that instead of shutting down the PC I clicked on Hibernate, I realised that and turned PC on again just to shut it down. I unfortunately don't have a restore point. So I will try creating a new User Profile and copy the files. Can you explain this a bit further ?

Comment: You just create a new user so your not using the built-in `Administrator` account.  In the future don't shutdown the computer without first taking it out of hibernation.

Comment: I took it out of hibernation and after that shut it down. It is the only think I can think of that caused the problem.

Comment: If you shut the computer down the correct way then that's not the reason the registry hive became corrupt.  Its likely because of a HDD problem I would clone the current drive and replace it.

Comment: Possible failing disk drive. Backup now. Check your hard disk for smart errors.

Comment: @DavidPostill I think the NTUSER.DAT file is corrupted. The file is located in the User Folder of the User Account (disable Hide protected operating system files). But I am still working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a New Local User Account. Then I logged in my Admin Account and deleted the User Account I couldn't sign in anymore. Windows 8.1 asked me if I wanted to save all the files of the User Account, which I did. After that I logged in the new created local User Account and connected it with my Microsoft Account and moved the saved files.